# Using only one user in cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, portable-applications

I installed Cygwin on USB stick. I'm going to use Cygwin on two computers. (My laptop and a desktop computer.)

Unfortunately, those two computer have a different user name. (user and ryang). So every time I switch those two computers, the location of user's home directory chages.

If I use Cygwin with `ryang`, the home directory is `/home/ryang`. If I use Cygwin with `user`, the home directory is in `/home/user`. But I want to use only one user, "sohnryang".

I don't want to change those two computer's settings. Any good solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not just that the two users are different for Cygwin, they are also different from Windows point of view.

To rename a cygwin user you can use the file `/etc/passwd`

```
 mkpasswd -c > /etc/passwd
 sed -e "s/ryang:/sohnryang:/g" -i /etc/passwd
```

and you can repeat it in the second computer

```
 mkpasswd -c >> /etc/passwd
 sed -e "s/user:/sohnryang:/g" -i /etc/passwd
```

so now both will share the same cygwin name.
The `:` is needed to change only the first and sixth fields; leaving untouched the fifth.

However the two users are different also for Windows as you can verify with

```
C:\Users\myself>whoami /user    
USER INFORMATION
----------------
User Name            SID
==================== =============================================
my_computer\myself   S-1-5-21-531030479-1339336681-3415091201-1009
```

The two SID's are different in the two computer also if the user names were the same in Windows.
The Windows User Name and SID are merged in the 5th field of `/etc/passwd`

The SID difference could cause authorization issue between files created on the two computer, depending on the type of system. Windows Home versions are usually more puzzling than Professional ones.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick solution -- *if you are the only Cygwin user on each machine* -- is to edit the file /etc/nsswitch.conf and set db_home to the desired home directory location:

```
db_home: /home/MyName
```

This does not actually change the user name itself.  If the directory is hardcoded in this manner, *ALL* users who log in to Cygwin will be set to use this same directory.  But for single-user systems, it's quick, easy, and works like a charm.